# XML Structure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following code which works fine and returns the expected results:

```
DECLARE @xmlList xml
SET @xmlList = '<Tx><T>1</T><T>2</T><T>3</T></Tx>'

SELECT
        X.Y.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS [ID], 'OK' AS [Status]
    FROM @xmlList.nodes('/Tx/T') X(Y)
```

However, it also accept when I provide it with the following structure and returns the ssame results:

```
SET @xmlList = '<Tx><T>1</T></Tx><Tx><T>2</T><T>3</T></Tx>'
```

Notice how I don't have a root element.

My question is, what do I need to change to make the code accept the first structure as valid and reject the other?

Thanks,

TheBlueSky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only want to query one `Tx` node (the first) you can do like this

```
SELECT
  X.Y.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS [ID], 'OK' AS [Status]
FROM @xmlList.nodes('/Tx[1]/T') X(Y)
```

You could also check the number of root nodes and call [raiserror](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) if you have more than one root.

```
select @xmlList.query('count(/Tx)').value('.', 'int')
```

The technique used before the `xml` datatype only accepted one root node. [sp_xml_preparedocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx) will raise and exception if there are more than one root.

```
declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @xmlList
exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Comment: It's kind of doing what I want to achieve although not directly. I'll accept the answer are T-SQL XML data type doesn't seem to support that natively.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enforce a specific structure of your XML, you can add a [XML schema to your SQL Server database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009.aspx) to check XML contents against a schema.

Go grab [The Art of XSD - SQL Server XML Schema Collections](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2009/04/26/my-latest-book-the-art-of-xsd-sql-server-xml-schema-collections-available-for-free-download.aspx) as a free PDF download to learn more about this

Comment: Do we have to go all the way to the sledgehammer cabinet and whip out XSD if all we want to do is establish that there is a single root element?

Comment: @AakashM: unfortunately, there is no easy, predefined way in SQL Server to test for XML well-formed-ness :-(

Comment: This solution is too complex for my requirement. Thanks for the information though.

Answer (score 0):

Root element is one and only one time. So in your example:

```
; With c as(
SELECT
        X.Y.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS [ID], 'OK' AS [Status]
    FROM @xmlList.nodes('//Tx') X(Y))
    SELECT COUNT(*) from c
```

In first case you will get 1, in second 2.

Comment: This is not at all what I was looking for.